# Counting Checked Radio Buttons with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have pages with varying numbers of radio buttons. These buttons have two different classes, `yes`, and `no`. As the user goes down the page, I need to figure out how many of each class they have selected, and display it in a `<p>` at the bottom of the page.

I'm having problems preventing 1 getting added to the variable when a user clicks on a radio button more than once. Here's a JS fiddle with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/AnWU3/3/

It's not working at all for some reason, and I don't see why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var yes = $('.yes:checked').length
        var no = $('.no:checked').length
        $('.yes_results').text(yes)
        $('.no_results').text(no)                        
    })
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AnWU3/4/)

Comment: Prefect, I'll accept as soon as it lets me. Not sure why I bother with jQuery when guys like you so completely pwn me lol.

Comment: I would avoid the use of the variables and simply inject the answer - avoids a small bit of mememory use/management.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than increment the values when one is clicked, do a count:

`$('input.yes:checked').length`

`$('input.no:checked').length`

Comment: Don't forget that you need to count only the checked ones. The count of inputs of a certain type wouldn't be right.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to put in the `:checked` part.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the change event and find the number of checked boxes each time.

```
$(".no,.yes").change(function() {        
    $('.yes_results').text($('.yes:checked').length);
    $('.no_results').text($('.no:checked').length);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AnWU3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would change it to

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
var nos = 0;
var yeses = 0;
$(".no").click(function() {

    if($('.no').is(':checked')) {
        nos = nos + 1;
        alert(nos);
    }
});
$(".yes").click(function() {

     if($('.yes').is(':checked')) {
        yeses = yeses + 1;
        alert(yeses);
    }
});
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the change event I think instead of the click event.

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){ 
   $('.yes_results').text($('input.yes:radio:checked').length) 
   $('.no_results').text($('input.no:radio:checked').length)                         
});
```

NOTE: Use the `input:radio` form over the `:radio` selector for speed which avoids a global search of the dom, limiting it to only the input elements.

Please limit the id to singular: `RadioGroup1_1` is a duplicate id.

Note: I used the class to count, you could use the `checked` property but I think the class will be faster based on other performance related questions/answers on SO.