# Counting Radio Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing an app with over 100 Q/A Flashcards and have added traffic light buttons to allow user to reflect on how well they understand each question/answer.

```
<form>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-theme="b" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
    <legend>Rate your understanding</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="traffic-lights" class="red" id="red" value="on" checked="checked">
        <label for="red"><img src="http://new.chemistry-teaching-resources.com/images/red-light18.png" width="18px" height="18px" ></label>
    <input type="radio" name="traffic-lights" class= "orange" id="orange" value="off">
    <label for="orange"><img src="http://new.chemistry-teaching-resources.com/images/Orange-light18.png" width="18px" height="18px"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="traffic-lights" class="green" id="green" value="other">
    <label for="green"><img src="http://new.chemistry-teaching-resources.com/images/green-light18.png" width="18px" height="18px"></label>
</fieldset>
```

The script is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$(".red,.orange,.green").change(function () {
    $('.red_results').text($('.red:checked').length);
    $('.orange_results').text($('.orange:checked').length);
    $('.green_results').text($('.green:checked').length);
});
```

});

To finish off I'd like to record the number of red/orange/green button clicks.

```
<p><span class="red_results">0</span> <img src="http://new.chemistry-teaching-resources.com/images/red-light18.png" width="18px" height="18px"> <span class="orange_results">0</span> <img src="http://new.chemistry-teaching-resources.com/images/Orange-light18.png" width="18px" height="18px"> <span class="green_results">0</span> <img src="http://new.chemistry-teaching-resources.com/images/green-light18.png" width="18px" height="18px"></p>
```

I've based it on a number of similar examples on stack overflow, mainly [Counting Checked Radio Buttons with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550453/counting-checked-radio-buttons-with-jquery).

I've got it working perfectly on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ginneswatsonkelso/k1u2f56o/1/ but doesn't work within my app.

The js I'm using are jquery-1.6.4.min.js, jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js and jquery-1.11.3.js and it works with all 3 on jsfiddle.

Presumably, I've done something wrong but I just can't see it.

The rest of my  is

```
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong link. Should have been http://jsfiddle.net/ginneswatsonkelso/k1u2f56o/1/

Comment: Uhh, it's working for me when I open your JSFiddle link.

Comment: Thanks NealC, but that's the problem. It works perfectly on JSFiddle and I can't understand why it will not still work within my app page.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Can we see more HTML? Unless Lyndsey solved your problem already. Like `<head>` for example?

Comment: Could you edit your question and change the link there, please? Are you using the same version of jQuery in the app as on the fiddle?

Comment: Wrong link corrected. Tried it with all 3 jQuery versions listed originally and it worked each time. Also tried with script in head and in body of html and again it worked each time on jsfiddle. As may be obvious, I'm very far from an expert and am quite likely making some basic mistake.

Comment: <head> is <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script src="js/flipCard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: don't post code in comments..update question itself. Do elements exist when code is run or are they part of ajax import? If import use `delegate()` to bind to ancestor that exists at run time

Comment: Thanks charlietfl - very new to this. I'd looked at examples using ajax but was well out of my depth. As far as I can tell, the example I'm basing my example on doesn't use ajax.

Comment: any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: Console in Safari says no errors. Bizarrely, Firefox comes up with "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."However, according to Dreamweaver, I don't have this anywhere, though it rings a bell from a previous discarded attempt.

Comment: Some progress. If I remove jQuery 1.6.4 then it works fine, but everything else is screwed up.

Comment: Then you're probably messing something up with some jquery calls in your code. And if this code still works (which requires jquery) you're probably loading multuple libraries/versions of jquery. Have you tried stepping through your function and seeing if it calls/where it breaks?

Comment: Thanks Jan. You're right in that I'm loading jquery-1.6.4.min.js, jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js and jquery-1.11.3.js. I'll have to try and simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event was brought in with jQuery version 1.7.

The version of jQuery you are running does not support the on() method. Previous versions of jQuery required [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), with the latter being the preferred method for event delegation.

If you are able to, you should look into updating your version of jQuery to use more up-to-date features.

Comment: Thanks LyndseyB. Not sure where the on() event is appearing in my code. Also it seems to work fine on jsfiddle with jQuery 1.6.4.

Comment: I referred to the JsFiddle you linked to: http://jsfiddle.net/A8tZd/ which uses the on() method. I can now see that you've posted a link to the relevant example.